# MediaWiki SearchEngine that behaves like google

Tags: google, mediawiki, sphinxsearch, search-engine, lucene

searchterm: `foo`
should match `foo` and `foobar`

searchterm: `"foo"`
should only match `foo`

I tried LuceneSearch and SphinxSearch so far, but I couldn't get any of these to behave like google. `foo` will only match `foo`, and `foo*` will match `foo` and `foobar`.

Comment: MediaWiki search is often problematic, but have you considered simply applying a Google Custom Search? It'd certainly line up with your requirements and it would probably save you some time/money testing out less-than-adequate alternatives.

Comment: @danlefree: That's not an option I'm afraid. The wiki is not publicly accessible.

Comment: Gotcha. There's also the option to acquire a Google search appliance if you're dealing with a corporate intranet and can expense it (linked). Favorited your question as I'm equally interested to see if anyone else has found an open source solution which beats Lucene and Sphinx. GSA: http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lucene](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lucene-search) does this, with one minor alteration: **foo***  (with an asterix) matches foo & foobar. "foo" does only match foo.

See Wikipedia's [Help:Searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching#Search_engine_features).